# Norm topology is the only topology that makes a vector space into a $T_1$ topological vector space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand how this statement:

If $X$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$, then the norm topology on $X$ is the unique topology on $X$ that makes $X$ into a $T_1$ topological vector space.

Is a direct consequence of this theorem:

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a $T_1$
 topological vector space over $\mathbb K$ and let $Y \subset X$ be a finite dimensional subspace of dimension n. Then a linear isomorphism $A: \mathbb K^n\to Y $ is also a homeomorphism.

I fail to see how the continuity of addition and scalar multiplication, which are the prerequisits for a topological vector space, follow from this theorem. Not to mention that I also don't understand how it implies that the topological vector space is $T_1$